# Choose input parameter value in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, parameters

I was thinking if it's possible to have a function's or sub's String (or Integer, not Boolean basically) input parameter to be selectable.

Let's say I have a Sub:

```
Public Sub PageSetup(Byval Orientation as String)
    'Some code here
End Sub
```

When I use this sub I want to choose Orientation from a list of items: Portrait, Landscape. Just like a Boolean offers to choose True or False.

I know I could use Boolean for this example, but I have other ideas where I wouldn't have only two options.

Maybe use Enum or simply arrays, I don't know, I couldn't do it with these.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are designed for this purpose.

See [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx):

```
Public Class Egg
    Enum EggSizeEnum
        Jumbo
        ExtraLarge
        Large
        Medium
        Small
    End Enum
End Class

Public Sub Scramble(ByVal size As Egg.EggSizeEnum)
    ' Process for the three largest sizes. 
    ' Throw an exception for any other size. 
    Select Case size
        Case Egg.EggSizeEnum.Jumbo
            ' Process. 
        Case Egg.EggSizeEnum.ExtraLarge
            ' Process. 
        Case Egg.EggSizeEnum.Large
            ' Process. 
        Case Else 
            Throw New ApplicationException("size is invalid: " & size.ToString)
    End Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks I couldn't figure out how to use Enums in parameters, my definitions was good. Thanks man.